# TypeError: undefined is not an object

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I'm having problems with the `onmouseover` command. I've got this little bit of code (see bottom) in my HTML code and when I try to run it on Safari 7 I get the following error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'document.images.siz3.src='images/shirts/img_3siz_grey.jpg'')
>   onmouseover

What's the problem? I can't find anything that could be wrong. The `img` should be defined as `siz1`, shouldn't it?

Maybe someone could help, I'm sure the answer's easy and I'm just not seeing it.

```html
<a href="menu/latein/r-z/vfc/vfc.html" onmouseover="document.images.siz1.src='images/shirts/img_1siz_grey.jpg'" onmouseout="document.images.siz1.src='images/shirts/img_1_siz.jpg'" name="tshirts">
<img src="images/shirts/img_1_siz.jpg" name="siz1“  alt="Vivat floreat crescat" width="195px" height="135px"></img>
```

Comment: Better to add the events in JavaScript. Inline events are bad practice. Look into `addEventListener`. Also, note the quotes `“ != "`.

Comment: Check the name attribute for the `img` tag. It was not declared correctly, I have edited it in the question as well. Can you try again if that was the issue?

Comment: Ah, thanks! It was the quotes...

Comment: If the images are really inside the links, as it seems they might be from your quoted HTML, you can use `onmouseover="this.firstElementChild.src = ..."` instead.

Comment: As this question is unlikely to be useful to others in the future, best thing to do is simply delete it with the "delete" link underneath it. (Edit: Sadly, now you can only flag it and ask a mod to, since someone has upvoted ozil's answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like problem in here `name="siz1“` should be `name="siz1"` replace `“` to `"`

Comment: [As elclanrs said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30977161/typeerror-undefined-is-not-an-object#comment49984847_30977161) - when posting someone else's comment as an answer, it's best to make it a CW.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I didn't look the comment

Answer (score 0):

You weren't closing the 'name' tag with the correct quotation mark.

```html
 <a href="menu/latein/r-z/vfc/vfc.html" onmouseover="document.images.siz1.src='images/shirts/img_1siz_grey.jpg'" onmouseout="document.images.siz1.src='images/shirts/img_1_siz.jpg'" name="tshirts">
<img src="images/shirts/img_1_siz.jpg" name="siz1"  alt="Vivat floreat crescat" width="195px" height="135px"></img>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="change('change')" onmouseout="change('')">Click</a>
<img id="siz1" src="images/shirts/img_1_siz.jpg" height="200" width="200" />
<script>
    function change(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById('r1').src = "images/shirts/img_1_siz.jpg";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('r1').src = "images/shirts/img_1siz_grey.jpg";
        }
    }
</script>
```